# Maximum equal string subarray

Tags: c++, algorithm

Let's say I have two strings:

```
"hello"
"love"
```

The size of the maximum subarray in the strings is 2: "lo".

Here's another example:

```
"ABBABBA"
"BBABCBA"
Maximum subarray: "BBAB"
Size: 4
```

Basically, how can I solve this problem in the most efficient way?

My idea is the following:

- Generate all subarrays for one string
- Generate all subarrays for the other string;
- Compare all subarrays
- **The result is the size of the largest matching subarrays**

But I think this is some bad-looking brute force. Any idea of how I can improve this?

Thank you!

**EDIT**
I'll need the string too.

Comment: is it the longest common subsequence problem? maybe this http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence could help, even if there's no C++!

Comment: @ShinTakezou No, it's the longest common *substring* - it is much easier than LCS.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks, I've read too swiftly and unthinking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well-known problem called [Longest Common Substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). It can be solved in `O(mn)`, where `m` and `n` are lengths of the individual strings, using *dynamic programming* approach. The article in Wikipedia contains easy-to-follow pseudocode.

Comment: But the algorithm I found returns the length, I need the string too.

Comment: @user996056 There is a [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring) in the article that takes you to implementations in various languages. The second C# implementation there returns the string.

Comment: It can be solved much better that O(mn).  The optimal solution is O(m + n), which can be attained through a number of different graph algorithms.

Comment: @ex0du5 That's true, the article explains how to do it with a generalized suffix tree. It is a lot more complex to implement, though, so it's probably not worth it unless you're looking for matches among multiple strands of DNA :)